# Retrieving elements in a list perl

Tags: list, perl, element

I'm trying to retrieve an element from a list using perl using another variable that is assigned an integer.

```
    use File::Copy qw(move)
    my @List;
    my $newDir = "foo/bar";
    my $file = "foo/bar.txt";
    push @List, $file;
    my $file2 = "foo/bar2.txt";
    my $var = 1;
    push @List, $file2;
    move $List[$var-1], $newDir;
```

Instead of moving "file" the program fails.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I'm not getting one (it ends as if it was successful), but the file does not move. I should also note that I am indeed using strict and warnings.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $newDir = foo/bar;
```

There are quotes missing around the string:

```
my $newDir = 'foo/bar';
```

and similarly for other paths.

Also, are you sure you want to use a file name with a newline at the end in the `move` command?

Also, something like

```
use File::Copy;
```

is missing, too.

Moreover, check the return value of `move`:

```
move $List[$var-1], $newDir or die $!;
```

Comment: Just a note this is nothing like the actual code, but it's close enough to help me get the answer  I think I need. I corrected those things you pointed out for the psuedocode and even removed the new line parts from the real code but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @NotTheDoctor: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Any error messages? Do you check the return value of `move`, and if it's 0, do you check `$!`?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't move the file. I should probably explain what happens a bit more: the script creates a file and puts a bunch of data in it, when it reaches a certain limit (100k lines in this case) it creates a new file and moves the previous file to a different directory. This new file then has data added to it until the same thing happens. The issue is that when this new file is created the variable that stores the file name changes back to the old file name after the variables are reinitialized. No error message, the script just ends, even in debug mode it ends as if it's successful.

Comment: I hope that makes a bit more sense. The issue is that only the first file is moved, any following files are not moved. Thanks for your help really, I have never coded in perl before.

Comment: Ok I think I have it now, I'm waiting until that long while loop ends and then moving the files using a for statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have no lists in your code. You have an **array** called `@List`, but misnaming a variable doesn't change what it is. [Arrays are not lists](http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl).

Secondly, your code works exactly as expected for me. I've added error reporting on the `move` call. That might help track down your problem, but I suspect it's caused by files or directories not being where you think they are.

```
$ cat move 
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy qw(move);
my @List;
my $newDir = "foo/bar";
my $file = "foo/bar.txt";
push @List, $file;
my $file2 = "foo/bar2.txt";
my $var = 1;
push @List, $file2;
move $List[$var-1], $newDir or warn $!;

$ find foo
foo
foo/bar
foo/bar.txt

$ perl move

$ find foo
foo
foo/bar
foo/bar/bar.txt
```